# How to display images in ListView in Win8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

The problem:

There is no images being displayed.Please help to correct my mistake.  Thanks

1) I have stored the photo in a folder called Images and marked the photo as content

2) I have created a class and added it in the project

```
class ModelImage
{
    public string Image_Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

3) I have added the ListView and a Button in MainPage

```
<ListView Name="LV" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="552" Margin="693,27,0,0"    Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="582">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="Hello">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="300" Width="300">
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

--- Button

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List <ModelImage> list = new List <ModelImage>();
    {
        new ModelImage { Image_Name = "Meat", Image = "/Images/Meat_ProkChop.jpg", Description = "Pork Chop" };
        new ModelImage { Image_Name = "Meat", Image = "/Images/Meat_Beef.jpg", Description = "Beef" };
    };

    LV.DataContext = list;
}
```

Do I need to use the hardcode Path for the photo inside the folder called Images?

Comment: First of all, I'd use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`. Second of all, if you have direct access to the `ListView`, just set its `ItemsSource` directly. It's likely that it's not responding to its change in `DataContext`.

Comment: Not working, I tried LV.ItemsSource = list; Do you have any sample reference. THanks

Comment: It is considered polite to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try "ms-appx:///Images/Image.jpg" instead of "/Images/Image.jpg". Getting the path right is important. Since it is default, this is likely correct already, but ensure your images are marked as "Content" in properties.

Best of luck!